# Adding instance store volume to AWS C5 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volumes

Trying to run some HammerDB benchmarks and it appears that the new AWS C5 instances have no store volume. Is there any way to attach some?

Answer (score 0):

**C5** is **not supported** for instance store. See: [Amazon EC2 Instance Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-volumes)

Even if your instance type supports instance store:

> If you need additional instance store volumes, you must add them to
>   the instance as you launch it.

See: [Adding Instance Store Volumes to an Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html)?